# The best way to do an efficient filter query in django

Tags: django, django-models

## models.py file

I am not so good at this aspect in Django. Please can someone help me? I wish to know if there is a more efficient way for the class method **already_voted**

```
class Vote(TimeStamped):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), verbose_name=_("Vote"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contester = models.ForeignKey(Contester, verbose_name=_("Contester"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    help_text=("The chosen contester"), related_name="votes")
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(
    _("Voter's IP"), 
    protocol="both", 
    unpack_ipv4=False, 
    default="None",
    unique=True
    )
    num_vote = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Vote"), default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('voter','contester')
        verbose_name = _("Vote")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Votes")
    
        permissions = (
                   ("vote_multiple_times", "can vote multiple times"),
                  )
   ....
   ....
    @classmethod
    def already_voted(cls, contester_id, voter_id=None, ip_addr=None):
        return cls.objects.filter(contester_id=contester_id).exists() and \
           (cls.objects.filter(ip_address=ip_addr).exists() or \
           cls.objects.filter(voter_id=voter_id).exists())
```

Answer (score 1):

The class method may be right, but your model needs one more index:

```py
    contester = models.ForeignKey( db_index= True #... )
```

Notice that:

- `voter` doesn't need index because is on first place on `unique_together` constraint.
- `contester` needs index because, despite it is on `unique_together`, doesn't is place on first position of the constraint.
- `ip_address` doesn't need index because has `unique` constraint.

Also:

- `unique_together` is deprecated and should be a list of tuples (not just a tuple)

## Edited

**Edited** 5 feb 2021 due to OP comment

You can get results in just one hit using `Exists` but it is less readable, also, I'm not sure if it is more efficient or the best way:

```py
from django.db.models import Exists
q_ip=Vote.objects.filter(ip_address="1")
q_voter=Vote.objects.filter(voter=2)
already_voted=(
    Vote
    .objects
    .filter(contester=3)
    .filter(Exists(q_ip)|Exists(q_voter))
    .exists())
```

The underlying sql, you can see this is just one query:

```sql
SELECT ( 1 ) AS "a"
FROM   "a1_vote"
WHERE  ( "a1_vote"."contester" = 3
         AND ( EXISTS(SELECT U0."id",
                             U0."voter",
                             U0."contester",
                             U0."ip_address",
                             U0."num_vote"
                      FROM   "a1_vote" U0
                      WHERE  U0."ip_address" = '1')
                OR EXISTS(SELECT U0."id",
                                 U0."voter",
                                 U0."contester",
                                 U0."ip_address",
                                 U0."num_vote"
                          FROM   "a1_vote" U0
                          WHERE  U0."voter" = 2) ) )
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, it's greatly appreciated. I was wonder actually if there is a better way to write the **already_voted** method such that the number of times the query hits the database is as minimum as it can possibly be...

Comment: @Virtu_Acad, I rewrote answer to hit just one time the database. See answer comments.